# How to run PHP code (within same script) when HTML button is pressed

Tags: php, html

Really quick question, how can I run a line of PHP code when an HTML button is pressed. What I am trying to do is destroy a php session (to log the user out) when the logout button is pressed.

Thanks!

Comment: you have to use ajax

Comment: There is no other way to do it than to use ajax? Edit: And when I use ajax, it can all be within the same script? @melvin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use the button, then you should send a form to specific URL address where the session will be destroyed. If you want to use a link instead of a button, then you can point a specific URL address where your session code will be destroyed. All depends on your application architecture.
But in one word, you need to send HTTP request to a place where the session will be destroyed.

Comment: Oh okay! That's a good idea. That didn't really come to mind. Thank you so much! I will accept this as an answer in 4 minutes when it allows me to do so! :)

Comment: I'm, glad that this answer was helpful :)

Answer (score 0):

Basically you need to call js function which will be executed when you press the logout button. That will redirect user to logout url. and that url/script will destroy the session and redirect user to homepage.